# Passar variável em jQuery dentro do Ajax

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte Form:

```
<div class="row" id="importar">
    <form id="convidados">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $this->uri->segment(4); ?>" id="id_cliente" name="id_cliente">
        <div id="multiple_upload">
            <input type="file" id="uploadChange" onchange="checkfile(this);" />
            <div id="message">Selecione o Arquivo</div>
            <input type="button" id="botao_" class="btn btn-primary" value="Importar" disabled />
            <div id="lista">

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
<div>
```

E o jQuery:

```
// importar 
$(function () {

    var form;
    $('#uploadChange').change(function (event) {
        form = new FormData();
        form.append('uploadChange', event.target.files[0]); // para apenas 1 arquivo
        //var name = event.target.files[0].content.name; // para capturar o nome do arquivo com sua extenção
    });

    $('#botao_').click(function () {
        var id_cliente = $("#id_cliente").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: basePath + 'ajax/importar_lista',
            data: {upload: form, id_cliente: id_cliente},
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("success");     
                $('#importar').html("<div style='padding: 100px;'><center><img src='../../../assets/img/importando-lista.gif'></center></div>");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#importar').html(data);
                },3000);    
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Preciso adicionar a seguinte variável para repassar no ajax/importar_lista:

```
var id_cliente = $("#id_cliente").val();
```

Como eu posso passar o `id_cliente` dentro do ajax? Se eu repassar como a resposta do @KayoBruno, preciso repassar com var?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quiser passar o `form` todo coloca `data: form`, visto já ter uma variável global.

Outra coisa, em seu `new FormData` tem que ser assim:

```
form = new FormData($('form')[0]);
```

Tem que colocar o Elemento do Form dentro do `FormData`.

```
$('#botao_').click(function () {
    var id_cliente = $("#id_cliente").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: basePath + 'ajax/importar_lista',
        data: form,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("success");     
            $('#importar').html("<div style='padding: 100px;'><center><img src='../../../assets/img/importando-lista.gif'></center></div>");
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#importar').html(data);
            },3000);    
        }
    });
});
```

E no PHP normal:

```
$idCliente = $_POST['id_cliente'];
```

### HTML

```
<form id="convidados" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: É pra funcionar sim. Não está levando nada ? Você verificou se o campo hidden está com algum valor ?

Comment: O campo hidden tem valor, e não está levando nada.. ai se eu colocar data: form, ele leva só os dados do upload.. será que é por causa da função acima do jquery?

Comment: Antes de chamar o Ajax, faça `console.log($('form').serialize());` e veja o que retorna.

Comment: Retornou somente id_cliente=3

Comment: Mesma coisa... não consigo receber os dados do id_cliente, e dessa forma, nem os dados do upload, pode ser por causa do form? eu coloquei assim <form id="convidados">...

Comment: Boa observação, não havia me deparado. Tem parâmetros obrigatórios, como o `enctype`.

Comment: Estou sem sorte hoje, deu a mesma coisa rssrsrsr...

Comment: No PHP faça `print '<pre>'; print_r($_POST) print '</pre>';`

Comment: Já fiz, POST, GET, REQUEST E FILES todos retornam array()

Comment: Deixe apenas assim no AJAX: `data: $('form').serialize(),`

Comment: Numa tentativa, fiz da seguinte forma @Gumball: dentro do ajax... dados: {id_cliente: id_cliente}, ai com print_r($_REQUEST) ou POST, aparece. Além do data: form, eu acrescentei o dados:..

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50606/discussion-between-andre-baill-and-gumball).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode passar quantos parâmetros quiser no data.

```
$('#botao_').click(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: basePath + 'ajax/importar_lista',
    data: {form: form, id_cliente: id_cliente},
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("success");     
        $('#importar').html("<div style='padding: 100px;'><center><img src='../../../assets/img/importando-lista.gif'></center></div>");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#importar').html(data);
        },3000);    
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Mas eu preciso indicar o var?

Comment: não deu certo não...

Comment: Sim, precisa declarar a variável.